# Unable to run tests with jest.each

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, jestjs

I am trying to load files into an array and then run tests on them. This is my code:

```js
let files: string[] = []

describe.only("Name of the group", () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    files = ["a", "b"]
  })

  test.each(files)("runs", f => {
    console.log(f)
  })
})
```

However, I get

> Error: `.each` called with an empty Array of table data.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`test.each`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#describeeachtablename-fn-timeout) expects a table value as input. which means an array of arrays. But that is fixed automatically so don't worry about it.

But the call order is important here! Notice that the tests are defined before they are actually run. So, `beforeAll` will run after the tests were defined. This means the `files` array won't be defined while the tests are being registered.

In order to fix this, you need to make sure the `files` array is populated **before the tests are read and registered**

So something like this:

```js
const files: string[][] = [ ['test1'],['test2'] ];

describe('Something Something', () => {
  describe('Name of the group', () => {
    test.each(files)('runs %s', (f) => {});
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it makes no difference. I still get the same error: `.each` called with an empty Array of table data.

Comment: @mspoulsen fixed my answer to also deal with what you said in the comment

Comment: @mspoulsen if something is still unclear in the answer, please let me know. Or mark the answer as the right solution please

Comment: beforeAll(() => files = [["a"], ["b"]]) is not working in this example...but thanks for the answer...I think I got it.

Comment: beforeAll is executed before the test but not before initialization of .each. How would I load the filenames asynchronously?

Comment: Well... I tried myself and looks like you can't. But if you're working with filenames, you can do a [`readDirSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options) which should fetch the filenames synchronously

Comment: Jesus Christ! I have spent so much time on this issue. Had no idea there was a readdirSync! Thanks so much! Works like a charm :)

Comment: This answer should be edited, the first code snippet does not work.