# How to use Jest beforeAll to load test cases?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I am trying to load sample cases from an external source before tests run.  The following fails with the error ``.each `must be called with an Array or Tagged Template Literal. Instead was called with: undefined`.  Why is `beforeAll` not executing before the tests?

```js
let samples: string[];

beforeAll(() => {
  samples = ["first sample foo", "second foo sample"];
});

describe(`Test Samples`, () => {
  test.each(samples)("should include foo", (sample) => {
    // NEVER GETS HERE
    expect(sample.includes("foo")).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

You may ask why not load samples just before `describe`.  I am loading samples from an async source and `describe` does not support `async` modifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[troubleshooting#Defining Tests](https://jestjs.io/docs/troubleshooting#defining-tests)

> Tests must be defined synchronously for Jest to be able to collect your tests.

> This means when you are using `test.each` you cannot set the table asynchronously within a `beforeEach` / `beforeAll`

```
let samples: string[] = ["first sample foo", "second foo sample"];

// beforeAll(() => {
// samples = ["first sample foo", "second foo sample"];
// });

describe(`Test Samples`, () => {
  test.each(samples)("should include foo", (sample) => {
    expect(sample.includes("foo")).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/76282171/index.test.ts (13.983 s)
  Test Samples
    ✓ should include foo (19 ms)
    ✓ should include foo (2 ms)

  console.log
    sample:  first sample foo

      at stackoverflow/76282171/index.test.ts:10:13

  console.log
    sample:  second foo sample

      at stackoverflow/76282171/index.test.ts:10:13

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        15.106 s
```

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60093532/1140531) can help you.

In short, the problem is fetching data in `beforeAll` won't help as the tests are defined before they are actually run. So, `beforeAll` will run after the tests were defined. This means the `samples` array is empty when the tests are being registered.